# 'bower' and 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, gulp, gitlab, bower-install

I have installed npm via command `npm install` and it is suucessfully installed also.

I have executed this command `npm install gulp -g` and it is successfully installed.

When I run this command `npm install bower -g` I can see below warning:

```
We don't recommend using Bower for new projects. Please consider Yarn and Webpack or Parcel. You can read how to migrate legacy project here: https://bower.io/blog/2017/how-to-migrate-away-from-bower/
```

However below commands are throwing error when I run it in cmd.

```
bower install
```

Error : 'bower' is not recognized as an internal or external command

```
gulp dev-server
```

Error : 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

My system machine has node js installed.
Below are the paths for npm , git, nodejs and all I have included in path variables:

C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm\nom.cmd

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe

C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe

Path Variables:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm;C:\Users\677427\node_modules\bower\lib\node_modules;C:\Users\677427\node_modules\bower\bin
```

Comment: I have add below variable in path :

C:\Users\677427\AppData\Roaming\npm

Now bower install giving me the error :

bower ENOENT No bower.json present

Comment: You have to install gulp locally as well, I don't know anything about bower probably the same.